# Capture a screenshot and share it with social media

Tags: java, android, android-intent, screenshot, share

Here is an excerpt of the code. I can compile it, but the program crashes on the phone/emulator.

```
    Bitmap bitmap;
    View v1 = MyView.getRootView();
    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    String path = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bitmap,
            "title", null);
    Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse(path);

    final Intent socialIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    socialIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

    socialIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
    socialIntent.setType("image/png");
```

Anyone know how to do it? I want to capture a screenshot and let the user share it if he/she likes to. Everything else work, it's just the screenshot I cannot get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way a screenshot can be obtained is by having direct access to the frame-buffer which is at the kernel level, this in turn requires rooted access to accomplish this and to pull in the data from there to make up the graphics that is the screen itself.

This requires either a modded ROM for this purpose or having root privilege to do so. Sony, I know, do it, they have that facility in place to do so without root as the ROM is modified, in the power menu, there is an option 'Take Screenshot'. CM is another that requires root.

There is a facility available in ICS that has the programmatic API available to do this, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820587/android-ics-screen-capture-using-native-apis), but with earlier versions, you're out of luck.

Comment: Sort of correct, but not relevant to what this code is trying to do.  Instead, this code is attempting to write out the app's own view hierarchy as a bitmap (ie, "screenshot" itself).  That is possible, if done right.